# while Convert sql query to json getting wrong output

Tags: python, sql

```
# print(qry1.fetchall()) 
# print this [(1716, 'Mumbai Indians')]
# print(self.curs.description) 
# print this (('Highest_Extra_Runs', None, None, None, None, None, None), 
('Team', None, None, None, None, None, None))

items = []
for row in qry1:
    for
key in self.curs.description:
items.append({key[0]: value for value in row})
print(json.dumps({'items': items}))
```

I am getting wrong output

```
{"items": [{"Highest_Extra_Runs": "Mumbai Indians"}, {"Team": "Mumbai Indians"}]}
```

Output should be:

```
{"items": [{"Highest_Extra_Runs": 1716}, {"Team": "Mumbai Indians"}]}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with your nested loops. You actually want to parallely iterate both lists. The lists themselves are quite complex due to the nesting of lists and tuples. That's why you may loose track here. You could try simplifying the lists/objects if possible or storing parts of them in extra variables. It will make your job easier when dealing with them.

Now the solution to your problem: Instead of looping in foreach-manner, use an index and access the particular values in both lists/tuples.

```
items = []
for i in range(len(qry1[0])):
    items.append({self.curs.description[i][0]: qry1[0][i]})
print(json.dumps({'items': items}))

# Output:
{"items": [{"Highest_Extra_Runs": 1716}, {"Team": "Mumbai Indians"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did this

```
items = [dict(zip([key[0] for key in self.curs.description],row)) for row in 
qry1]
```

Comment: Of course a one-liner like this also works, but especially when you nest two list comprehensions like here, I would highly recommend not doing this. It may use less lines of code, but that's not the metric for quality code. High quality code provides great readability, so rather spend one "normal" for loop to make the list comprehension a bit easier. You will thank yourself in the future when reading this code again. Such one-liners quickly add a huge level of complexity which is error prone.

Comment: I agree with you that code readability and quality matter but your code giving an error 'sqlite3.Cursor' object is not subscriptable